# Style TreeviewItem with Powershell

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, treeview

I'm learning powershell and doing a small script, which checks a log file for some conditions. The results are then displayed in a GUI. GUI is made with XAML. Is it possibile to change color for child items individually? Can I also color a part of the string for instance in red, the other in green?

Thank you...

The function I use to add Items:

```
Function AddChild ($content, $color) {

if ($color) {
    $ime.AddChild($content)
    #here I would like to change the color
} else {
 $ime.Items.Add($content)

}
```

}

My XAML looks like this:

```
    <TreeView Name="tree" Height="374" Margin="5,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450">

            <TreeViewItem Name="ime" Header="JOBa">

            </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that `$content` is the `TreeViewItem` you're trying to add to `$ime`, set the [`Foreground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Background`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(v=vs.110).aspx) properties to set colors:

```
if ($color) {
    $content.Foreground = $color
}
$ime.Items.Add($content)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry doesn't work. $content is the text wich appears in the treeview child item. for this item I'd like to change the color. $ime is the name of the treeview. I get this error: "Property 'ForeGround' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable."

Answer (score -1):

I am not positive that this can be pushed to a XAML File but you would want to change the color in line with the Write command, take a look at the code from one of my scripts below.

```
    ([ADSI]"WinNT://$_/Administrators,group").add($Trustee)
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Successfully completed command"
```

if you look in the second line that is where I change the Foreground Color (Text) to green if this is completed, and the else part of this If I change to red so I can quickly tell where it has issues.

Does this help, if not can you clarify what you mean.

Luke

Comment: Write-host command works only for the command prompt and not for a GUI. I would like to change the color of a treeview child item in my GUI. Any ideas?